# Add Tesseract to the output directory C#

Tags: c#, uwp, tesseract

This is starting to annoy me. I have a UWP that allows you to open up a separate windows forms app to take advantage of tesseract. The app works fine when running on its on, however as soon as I call upon it to run using the UWP, the app crashes and gives me the error that it could not find the file specified, that file being the tesseract folder. I have it referenced within the app as

```
var path = "C:\\Users\\dan\\source\\repos\\TesseractApp\\packages\\Tesseract.4.1.1";
```

Is this something really simple I'm missing? If anything I'd like to copy the Tesseract.4.1.1 folder to directory, but that doesn't seem to work either. Hopefully this is clear.

EDIT - I believe it is just the exe file not working properly. I think I'm not copying over enough files into the Assets folder of the UWP and the exe of the tesseract app does not have what it needs to work.

Comment: are you referencing your source code directory? try to find the directory by some environment variable instead.

Comment: @LeiYang What do you mean by that? The source code directory as in the one for my UWP or the one for the TesseractApp?

Comment: can you paste error messages or stacktrace?

Comment: Are you trying to “open” a file? You state that… _”gives me the error that it could not find the file specified, that file being the tesseract folder.”_ … ? … A file is not the same thing as a folder. The path you show looks like a “FOLDER” not a “FILE”… The error makes sense in that there does not appear to be a “file” name in the posted path.

Comment: @LeiYang I would love to, however once the debugging engine opens up a new window of visual studio, nothing happens. No error is displayed, just a blank window, which is annoying. However it went something like Failed to find file specified Tesseract.4.1.1 PublicTOken=Null etc. Ill keep trying to get the actual message

Comment: @JohnG Honestly, I think tesseract uses the folder as an entrance to open up what it needs. When I am running the app that contains the tesseract code only, it works perfectly fine, no error. It is only when opening the tesseract app from my UWP do I get that error that tesseract could not be loaded